# Questions regarding Wish+Simulacrum

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, wish, simulacrum

An 18th level Divination wizard uses his 9th-level slot and *wish* to cast Simulacrum on himself as an action at the start of combat.  Provided he had just started the adventuring day, and hadn't spent any other spell slots or class resources, am I mistaken in assuming that:

1. aside from the inability to regain hitpoints (through conventional
   healing)
2. or to regain spell slots
3. not to mention the high vulnerability to Dispel Magic,

*the wizard can effectively double his spellcasting capacity, slots and all*? On the condition that this assumption is correct:

1. Does the Simulacrum have the wizard's class features, such as Portent?
   (If so, does it roll new Portents or just keep what the wizard already had?)
2. Does the simulacrum have a 9th level spell slot available, since on was spent by casting *wish*?
3. Can the wizard and the simulacrum both cast spells on the same turn, levelled or otherwise, provided they both had the slots for them?
   If so, can the wizard and the simulacrum concentrate on two different spells at once?
4. **Bottom line: does using *wish* to cast simulacrum *double the caster's available spell slots*?**

Comment: I see four, maybe only three (if you treat the double spell slots and ability to cast 9th level spell as one) very different questions, here. You might want to split up each question into separate question posts. [While it's not a hard and fast rule](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6453/23064), we want to make sure that [each question gets the attention it deserves](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5904/23064).

Comment: Also note that you cannot regain a slot over level 5 with arcane recovery.

Comment: The edit was mostly for format, but also to clarify the question slightly.  Please review the edit and revise it again in case any meaning was muddied in the edit I made.